# Calling function dynamic in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

maybe a dumb question but can't find it. Is it possible to call a function (just like in php) dynamic.

php:

```
$data = new {$dynamic};
```

javascript:

```
var data = something.{dynamic}.getData(); //<-- this is not working
```

Is there anyway to do this in javascript?

Comment: `something[dynamic].getData()`

Comment: Did you mean `something[dynamic].getData()`?

Comment: Yes thank  didn;t know where to look.